# Django agregation with parameters

Tags: django, postgresql, orm

My task is - i want for each `object1` get latest `object2` by its `creation date`. But firstly i want to apply some filter:
Orm query:

```
    Object2.objects.filter(status='fail').annotate(max_date=
Max('object1__object2__created')).filter(created=F('max_date')
```

And its works fine if last created `object2` having `fail status` - but if it have another status - i get no result for this object, because `Max` looks on all objects not just `status='fail'` and if latest object have another `status` - i dont get any result for this `object1`

When i look on sql query it generated i see that its don't filter objects in `Max` by `status='fail'` it get all related objects - is where a way to achieve that i want? Can i somehow pass query to Max?

Sql:

```
    SELECT ....,  MAX(T3."created") AS "max_date" FROM "object2" INNER JOIN 
"object1" ON ( "object2"."object1_id" = "object1"."id" ) LEFT OUTER JOIN 
"object2" T3 ON ( "object1"."id" = T3."object1_id" ) WHERE "object2"."status" 
= fail GROUP BY ... HAVING "object2"."created" = (MAX(T3."created"))
```

Instead of `LEFT OUTER JOIN "object2" T3 ON ( "object1"."id" = T3."object1_id" )`

I want something like `LEFT OUTER JOIN "object2" T3 ON ( "object1"."id" = T3."object1_id" and "object2"."status" = fail)`
How can i achieve this?

Comment: but you have your logic by where clause `WHERE "object2"."status" = fail `

Comment: yes, but when this query calculate max created date - it search throught all objects2 not only one which have status 'fail' look at the query.
Its just get all related objects not only 'fail' -  "object2" T3 ON ( "object1"."id" = T3."object1_id" )

Comment: add your models please